# Mail.app with Yahoo! account

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, apple-mail, yahoo-mail

How can I use a vanilla Yahoo! account (free) with mail.app in Snow Leopard?
I note that with my iPod Touch I can access my Yahoo! account without a single problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use client applications to access a Yahoo! email account, unless you have a Yahoo! Plus email account. I believe you can access Yahoo! mail using the Mail app on the iPhone and iPod Touch without a Plus account, though.

Comment: +1 ... because it's Mac OS X. for Windows there is YPOPS: http://ypopsemail.com/